# What's the pronoun for "object of a preposition"?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, subordonnées, pronoms-relatifs

I just learnt [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/meaning-of-de-hauts-murs-que-dominent-des-cypres) that, there are different pronouns that each could connect the main clause and subordinate relative clause and serve as a particular role in the relative clause:

- *qui* acts as the subject of the relative clause;
- *que* acts as the direct object of (the verb of) the relative clause;
- *dont*, *à qui*, *au(x)quel(le)(s)*, etc, acts as indirect object of (the verb of) the relative clause.

Well, then is there a concept of “object of a preposition” in French?
For example, in English, in

> I study French with the help of google translation.

“google translation” is the object of the preposition *of*,
and “the help of google translation” is the object of preposition *with*.

If yes, what kind of pronoun shall be used?, or, as example, how to translate such questions to French?

> With what do you study French?
>
> With the help of what do you study French?

Sorry the questions in English are bad enough, but I hope you guys could catch what I mean…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interrogative pronouns are preceded by the appropriate preposition, just as in English:

> D'où venez vous?
>
> Avec qui étudies-tu?
>
> Dans combien de temps arriveras-tu?

However, for objects and persons, the pronouns in relative propositions are *lequel* and its variants (*laquele, lesquels, lesquelles*), preceded by the appropriate prepositions *unless* that preposition is *de* or *à*, in which the *le* is replaced accordingly by the appropriate combination: du/des/au/aux/à la.

Persons can use these pronouns, but I believe (I don't have my Grevisse at hand to check) that *qui* is still preferred.

> C'est le supérieur auquel/à qui je faisais référence. (He's the superior to which I referred.)
>
> C'est l'aéroport duquel je suis parti. (It's the airport from which I departed [amongst a specific selection, *dont* and *d'où* are more generic].)
>
> C'est le manuel avec lequel j'étudie. (It's the manual with which I study.)
>
> C'est l'entreprise pour laquelle je travaille. (It's the company for which I work.)

but (preferred forms, but *-quel* pronouns are still allowed and grammatical)

> C'est l'ami avec qui j'étudie.
>
> C'est l'homme pour qui je travaille.
>
> C'est l'ami dont je t'ai parlé. (*duquel* not possible here)

---

Now, regarding *dont* vs. *duquel*, it gets a bit more complicated. In basic relative construction, *dont* almost always has priority, at least with persons (and *d'où* is usually an allowed alternative when it's a locative preposition).

*Duquel* and its variants (*desquels, de laquelle, desquelles*) seem to appear in two situations:

1) When the *de* is part of a compound preposition (look at news search on google, *au cours de*, *lors de* and *à l'issue de* are particularly common):

> Le mois *au cours duquel* ces événements se sont produits [...]
>
> Les techniques *à l'aide desquelles* on peut distinguer ces espèces [...]

2) When there is a possessive construction as the opener of the relative (but then these are close to the above too, maybe it's just that *dont* cannot be used if the relative is opened by a compound preposition):

> Un des anglais, près de l'habitation duquel le combat avait commencé [...]
>
> Ils en construisent des bouteilles au goulot desquelles ils attachent une canule de bois.

Comment: thanks! so auquel = à qui je, duquel = dont, avec/pour lequel/laquelle/... = avec/pour qui. Hmm, why in the last example "duquel" is not possible?

Comment: @athos I think that would be best discussed by expanding my answer.

Comment: Typos qui iront mieux dans les exemples, surtout pour nos amis étrangers : "C'est le supérieur auquel/à qui je faisaiS référence" / "C'est la SOCIETÉ (je suppose) pour laquelle je travaille." / "Le mois au cours duquel ces événementS se sont produits." De rien ne me remerciez pas.

Comment: @Istao *Entreprise* est correct, du moins au Québec d'où j'écris. C'est *compagnie* qui est considéré incorrect. Il était minuit passé lorsque j'ai rédigé la première partie. Merci à Stéphane pour les corrections.

Comment: @Istao: Oui, j'ai utilisé *entreprise*, mais pourquoi pas *société* en effet, je ne sais pas lequel est le plus proche de *company*.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Au Québec, on distingue la *société* (i.e. la société par actions, qui est une personne morale), et l'*entreprise* qui est plus générique et inclue les opérations commerciales non distinctes de leurs propriétaires. *Company* ne fait pas habituellement cette distinction, si je me souviens bien.

Comment: @Circeus , thanks, let me summarize again. 

1. question sentences' format are driven by the preposition preceding its Interrogative pronouns.  de or à are special case.

2a. avec/pour/...(except de or à) qui = avec/pour/... lequel/laquelle/lesquels/lesquelles; 

2b. à qui = auquel; 

2c. dont = duquel/desquels/de laquelle/desquelles/d'ou . 

3. In 2a or 2b, prep. + qui is preferred when refeering to somebody, instead of something.

4. for 2c, dont has a priority unless de is in a locution (e.g. compound preposition), e.g. au cours de, à l'aide de, près de.

Comment: @athos Yes, roughly. I'm not 100% sure about point 3, but it's probably a good enough rule of thumb. For completeness (although it is not directly related to your question, it explains the nuance in the *aéroport/suupérieur* examples), I should add that the *-quels* pronouns are also the interrogatives used where English has *which*: *D'où es-tu parti?*="where did you leave from?" vs. *Duquel es-tu parti?*="which one did you leave from?".